# Mapping lookup/junction table entity in many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm attempting to map a many-to-many relationship **and** include the lookup/junction table entity and I'm having some trouble.  Here are my (basic) models:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public IList<UserGroupCode> Codes { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public IList<UserGroupCode> Codes { get; set; }
}

public class UserGroupCode
{
    public int UserGroupCodeId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the configuration for `User` I've been working with

```
HasMany(p => p.Codes).WithMany().Map(m =>
{
    m.ToTable("UserGroupCodes");
    m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
    m.MapRightKey("UserGroupCodeId");
});
```

I've seen a lot of articles on how to map many-to-many relationships which don't include the lookup table as an entity (the classic example is User-Roles relationships).  But, as you can see, I have a `Value` property on my `UserGroupCode` relationship which necessitates that relationship being an actual entity.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up coming across [this](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/03/12/avoid-many-to-many-mappings-in-orms/) article.  I added navigation properties to my `UserGroupCode` model for `User` and `Group`.

```
public class UserGroupCode
{
    public int UserGroupCodeId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The only configuration required for the relationship is on the `UserGroupCode` entity:

```
HasRequired(p => p.User).WithMany(p => p.Codes).HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId);
HasRequired(p => p.Group).WithMany(p => p.Codes).HasForeignKey(p => p.GroupId);
```